# Why did the bounty hunters try to run away from Galaxy One?

Tags: final-space

In the first episode of wonderful cartoon [Final](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4EHbt_kSkG8) [Space](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6317068/), the prison ship "Galaxy 1" is boarded by a group of bounty hunters. The SAMES robots are quickly overwhelmed and it seems that Gary and Moonkcake are in serious trouble - until the ship AI decides to active the FTL drive  - the "light folding core".

The mercenaries start to panic and try to run away, only to have their ships destroyed by sort of shockwave from the FTL drive (phenomena that has been weaponised at least once more in the show). All, except one of them, who hides and survives.

Why were they running in the first place instead of staying in the relative safety of the ship? Has there been any Word of God about this strange behavior?

Comment: Yeah it was odd why run seems pointless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that all of the ships are destroyed as they are either attached to the ship or close to it, we could assume that the FTL drive in this series creates a spacetime bubble for the ship to travel in that can only protect galaxy 1.

Since the bounty hunters know this they are probably running to protect their ships and would be able to continue pursuit thereafter, by getting out of the way of the FTL bubble and light folding themselves.

As we see Avocado doesn't run. Possibly because he is smarter, or doesn't care about his ship too much.

Comment: We see later in the season why Avocato probably cares more about capturing the target than he does about his ship.